# Virtualbox - Installed Ubuntu to raw partition, but won't boot up in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtualbox

I have managed to install the latest version of Ubuntu to raw partitions in VirtualBox. But now when i try to boot it up in VirtualBox it's giving me:

```
error: Unknown filesystem.
grub rescue> _
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, can anybody help? It's allowing me to type in it, but not recognizing sudo.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grab a live cd and reboot ;)
is your boot partition set active?
what says 
   `sfdisk -l`
how does your grub.cgf look like?
   `./boot/grub/grub.cfg`

maybe this links help a bit 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: Yup I've booted with live CD, and I get an asterisk under the col 'Boot' next to the device I originally installed the boot loader to /dev/sdb2. Does that mean it's active? From the live cd 'sudo nano ./boot/grub/grub.cfg' the file doesn't appear to exist/empty.

Comment: yep, looks fine
then unmount /dev/sdb2 ->
`umount /dev/sdb2` ->
`mount /dev/sdb2 mnt/sdb2` ->
`grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/sdb2 /dev/sdb`
ps. maybe you have to check that your bios does boot from sdb and not from sda

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work so I did another install and set /dev/sda as the boot loader and, Ubuntu booted up fine :)